# CHMOD in dockerfile for python

Tags: python, docker, permissions, dockerfile

I have a python script that downloads another script and executes it. Unfortunately the second script can't be downloaded due to the lack of permission.

Error:

`retrbinary("RETR " + filename ,open(filename2017-06-14 14:16:28 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'aa.py'`

I tried to give CHMOD permission by using this dockerfile:

`FROM python:3
ADD ftapp.py /
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN CHMOD 777 usr/var/app/
CMD [ "python", "./ftapp.py" ]`

Comment: run this with sudo

Comment: RUN SUDO CHMOD? Do I need to install sudo first?

Comment: Do not install sudo for a docker container. Never do this! Read the documentation carefully: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy. Per the documentation look at the line starting with "You should avoid installing or using sudo"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD ftapp.py .
RUN CHMOD 777 /usr/src/app/
CMD [ "python", "ftapp.py" ]
```